# How to get values out of an Expression<Action<T>>?

Tags: c#, linq-expressions, hangfire

I have a very strange test that I am writing that tests if an email is sent. We use hangfire so I have a wrapper IHangfireWrapper so that I can mock the Enqueue method. This Enqueue method takes one parameter(`Expression<Action<T>>`).

So if I wanted to use this method it would look something like this.

```
_ServiceProvider.HangfireWrapper
    .Enqueue<HangfireTasks>(x => x.SendEmail(subject, body, to));
```

Where I am passing in a string for subject, body, and to.

So this is the tricky part. I want to mock this call so I can look at the subject, body and to strings.

I have this code that works and I can get back the strings I want but Its super ugly.

```
var hangfireMock = new Mock<IHangfireWrapper>();

string body = null;
string subject = null;
string to = null;

hangfireMock.Setup(x => x.Enqueue(It.IsAny<Expression<Action<HangfireTasks>>>()))
    .Callback<Expression<Action<HangfireTasks>>>(expr =>
    {
        object parameters = ((ConstantExpression)((MemberExpression)((MethodCallExpression)expr.Body).Arguments[0]).Expression).Value;
        body = (string)parameters.GetType().GetField("body").GetValue(parameters);
        subject = (string)parameters.GetType().GetField("subject").GetValue(parameters);
        to = (string)parameters.GetType().GetField("to").GetValue(parameters);
    });
```

Is there a better/shorter way to do this? (does this code make any sense even?)

Comment: I looks suspiciously like you're trying to unit test a third party library. If so, that's generally considered bad form as A) it's hard to do B) if you find something you can't really fix it. Report bugs you find, but don't worry about testing for them.

Comment: We use Hangfire to fire off our emails, I am testing that the subject, body, and addresses of the email are what we are expecting. We do wrap hangfire in an interface so that we can mock calls to it.

Comment: Another way to test your code that works with Hangfire is to inject an IBackgroundJobClient into the class that is calling the Enqueue method.  This approach is described in the Hangfire documentation here: http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/writing-unit-tests.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing might work for your version of the compiler and as long as you always form the lambda exactly like that.

Here are some example lambdas for which it won't work:

```
x => x.SendEmail("subject", "body", "to")
x => x.SendEmail(subject, subject, to)
```

What you should do instead is to take the `Arguments` of the `SendEmail` call and evaluate each of them by creating a lambda expression for it and then compiling it:

```
var arguments = ((MethodCallExpression)expr.Body).Arguments;
subject = Expression.Lambda<Func<string>>(arguments[0]).Compile()();
body = Expression.Lambda<Func<string>>(arguments[1]).Compile()();
to = Expression.Lambda<Func<string>>(arguments[2]).Compile()();
```

Compiling an expression is relatively expensive, so it would make sense to interpret the expressions instead. [You have that choice on .Net Core](http://dotnet.github.io/api/System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%601.html#System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_1_Compile_System_Boolean_) and you probably also will in some future version of .Net Framework.